Proof: Let $M$ be a manifold then $M\setminus p$ isn't compact.

Let $M$ be a manifold and $p \in M$. Then $M \setminus p$ isn't compact.

I have seen some proofs of this with open covers and so on, but i wonder if the following proof is correct:
Proof:
Let $\kappa: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a chart around $p$. Let $ U \supset \overline{B_{\epsilon}(p)} := \kappa ^{-1}(\overline{B_{\epsilon}(\kappa(p)})$. This is a compact subset of $U$ and $M$. Because $M$ is hausdorff $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(p)}$ is closed.
Now assume $M \setminus p$ is compact: $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(p)} \setminus p$ is closed in the subspace topology and thus compact. But $\kappa$ maps $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(p)} \setminus p$ to $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(\kappa(p)}) \setminus \kappa(p)$ which is known to be not compact.
Is it correct to assume that $\kappa$ is still continous w.r.t the subspace topology?

You probably want to assume that the dimension is bigger than $0$.

Also, wouldn't it be much easier to just use sequences? The manifold is not sequentially compact (if $p$ is not an isolated point, which could only happen if the dimension is zero) and thus not compact.

To assume manifold, is very strange. All you need is $M$ $T_2$ and $p$ not isolated.

Your proof looks fine. Notationally I find it confusing to call the preimage of ${\rm Cl} B_d (\kappa (p), \varepsilon)$ as ${\rm Cl} B_d (p, \varepsilon)$; I will use $C$ for the preimage instead. It might help to explicitly show that $C - \{p\} \subseteq M - \{p\}$ is closed (despite being rather trivial): $C - \{p\} = (M - \{p\}) \cap C$, and $C \subseteq M$ is closed since it is a compact subspace of a Hausdorff space. Then, with regards to your concern about the continuity of $\kappa$ used to complete the proof by contradiction, we have the following simple fact:

If $\kappa: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, and $A \subseteq X$, then $\kappa_{|A}: A \to \kappa (A)$ is a homeomorphism when $A, \kappa (A)$ are taken as subspaces of $X, Y$, respectively.

This fact is easy to show.

The bijectivity of $\kappa_{|A}$ follows from the injectivity of $\kappa$ on $A$ and the fact that we restrict the codomain of $\kappa_{|A}$ to $\kappa (A)$.
Let $V \subseteq \kappa (A)$ be open; then, there is some $V' \subseteq Y$ open such that $V = \kappa (A) \cap V'$. Note that $\kappa_{|A}^{-1} (V) = A \cap \kappa^{-1} (V') \subseteq A$ is open since $\kappa^{-1} (V') \subseteq X$ is open.
Let $U \subseteq A$ be open; then there is some $U' \subseteq X$ open such that $U = A \cap U'$. Note that $\kappa_{|A} (U) = \kappa (A) \cap \kappa (U') \subseteq \kappa (A)$ is open since $\kappa (U') \subseteq Y$ is open.

Applying this fact to your problem, we can take $X = M$, $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$, and $A = M - \{p\}$.
Edit: Of course, it's important to consider manifolds with dimension $n > 0$. Otherwise, ${\rm Cl} B_d (\kappa (p), \varepsilon) - \{\kappa (p)\} = \emptyset$ is trivially compact.
